# Вызов параметризованного метода или метода параметризованного класса из коллекции

Tags: generics, scala

Есть следующая задача для Scala. Нужно хранить в коллекции экземпляры типа Record. Причем конкретные экземпляры этого типа должны как-то наследовать метод `write(a: A): Unit`, где `A` - тип значения, свой для каждой конкретной реализации `Record`. Далее приведен пример реализации на абстрактных типах:

```
trait RecValue
{
  type A
  def value: A
}

trait Record
{
  type A <: RecValue
  def read(): A
  def write(v: A): Unit 
}

class StringRecord extends Record
{
  type A = StringValue
  override def read(): A = {new StringValue("abc")} 
  override def write(v: A): Unit = {println(v)}
}

class StringValue(private val v: String) extends RecValue
{
  type A = String
  override def value: String = v 
}
```

Вроде все ок. Проблема возникает, когда вызывается метод `write` для элемента из коллекции:

```
val a = new StringRecord
val b = new StringValue("aga")
a.write(b) // С конкретным типом все работает

Console println List[Record](a)(0).read() // и тут все замечательно работает!
List[Record](a)(0).write(b)  // а вот здесь - не компилируется!
```

компилятор выдает ошибку типа

```
[error]  found   : b.type (with underlying type sample.StringValue)
[error]  required: _1.A where val _1: sample.Record
[error]         List[Record](a)(0).write(b)
[error]                                  ^
```

Как можно (да можно ли?) это обойти без явного приведения типа? Хочется также сохранить общие свойства данной иерархии классов, чтобы `RecValue` были соответствующих типов для соответствующих `Record`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, нельзя.

Вот чуть более простая версия проблемы:

```
val a: Record = new StringRecord  // поднимаю тип до `Record`
val b = new StringValue("aga")
a.write(b) // не компилируется
```

А не компилируется потому, что `Record.write` ничего не знает о `StringValue`. А информации о том, что `StringValue` наследник `RecValue` для него недостаточно.
Представим, что метод `Record#write` принимал бы любого наследника `RecValue`, в таком случае я бы мог подсунуть в `StringRecord` какой-нибудь `IntValue`:

```
val a: Record = new StringRecord
val intV = new IntValue(77)
a.write(intV)
```

---

Другими словами, тип нужный `Record` в коллекции нужно явно приводить к типу наследника, как-то так:

```
List[Record](a).head match {
  case el: StringRecord => el.write(b)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, неплохой вариант - использовать сопоставление с образцом. В этом случае можно надеяться на компилятор, предупреждающий о недостающих case-ветках; в моей задаче трейты вполне могут быть sealed, чтобы это работало в полную силу.

Comment: Еще можно попробовать type classes.